# Writing Query in Microsoft Access, error in field description

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am writing a query in Microsoft Access. and I am getting a syntax error in "field description". Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE CONS 
( 
    Com_Type text, 
    Cons_2008 double(10,2), 
    Cons_2009 double(10,2), 
    Cons_2010 double(10,2) 
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE CONS 
( 
  Com_Type TEXT(150), 
  Cons_2008 DOUBLE, 
  Cons_2009 DOUBLE, 
  Cons_2010 DOUBLE
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify the length of the text field, unless you want a field of length 255 when called through an Access query or a `Memo` field when called through an ADO connection.

```
Com_Type Text(50),
```

The `Double` type has no size and scale specifications. Either drop them or use the `Decimal` type.

```
Cons_2008 Double
```

Or

```
Cons_2008 Decimal(10, 2)
```

---

Note: See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181169/880990) for a limitation related to the decimal type.

---

When using the `Double` type, you can still specify a format in the `TextBoxes` linked to this table column. That way you can force the display of 2 decimals.

Comment: I made a test with Access XP and placed the CREATE TABLE query into an Access query. It creates a `Text` field with length 255. Maybe it behaves differently when executed through ADO. You have to use the type `Memo` when called through an Access query.

Comment: I see, they *do* behave differently. (I've only ever done DDL via an ADO connection.) Thanks for letting me know.