# Create Table query is giving syntax error due to decimal format

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007. There is following query to create the table.

I am trying to set max length as 12 and 2 for decimal precision for quantity column

```
create table tbl_sales
(
     sales_id autoincrement primary key,
     item_id number,
     quantity_sold double(12, 2)
)
```

but due to some reasons it gives syntax error message at double. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

`Double` has no parameters for precision or scale. It's a fixed 8-byte floating point format.

I still like this overview of data types best:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html

For `DECIMAL (precision, scale)` it states:

> Not available in the Access query interface or DAO. Use ADO to Execute the DDL query statement.

So you will have to do exactly this if you want to run a `CREATE TABLE` statement with `Decimal` type.

Alternatively, use DAO with the [`Database.CreateTableDef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createtabledef-method-dao) method.

---

If you want to use `Double`, it's just that.
This works for me in Access 2010, executed from query design:

```
create table tbl_sales
(
     sales_id autoincrement primary key,
     item_id long,
     quantity_sold double
)
```

Note that `number` also creates a Double column, so if you want Long Int for an ID column, use `Long`.

Comment: how do i declare precision and scale with double?

Comment: As I wrote, you can't. `Double has no parameters for precision or scale. It's a fixed 8-byte floating point format.`

Comment: then how do I mention correct scale and precision with script? may be decimal?

Comment: I feel we are running in circles. :) If you want defined scale and precision, then yes: use Decimal. There are several ways to script it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180929/how-do-i-create-a-decimal-field-in-access-with-alter-table @Pankaj

Answer (score -1):

There are two major problems in the quer.
First The auto increment is not correct.
Second there should be decimal in place of double.
here is the query .

```
   create table tbl_sales
(
     sales_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
     item_id number,
     quantity_sold Decimal(12, 2)
)
```

Comment: I am using 2007, it is not accepting `auto_increment`. instead `autoincrement` works fine. `Decimal(12, 2)` not working in 2007

Comment: You can use the design view to create the table. If you insist to use query. Use number data type, and it will work fine.